# How to assign or add a new problem 'label' to an ever-increasing collection of reviews?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, artificial-intelligence, data-science

So basically I have a dataframe which looks like:

```
user_id, comment
0, 'Functional but Horrible UI'
1, 'Great everything works well'
2, 'I struggled finding plus button because of theme colors in dark mode'
3, 'Keeps stopping on Android 10'
4, 'I like the functionaity but color theme could be better'
5, 'Consistently crashing. Uninstalled'
6, 'Good overall'
7, 'sfdfsdlfksd'
8, 'I lost in complex settings'
9, 'Configuring app is really a headache'
10, 'aaaaaaaaaaaaa'
```

And I want to figure out some data science approach to pluck out information about what users are struggling with and which issues appeared how much and stuff like this. Even some simple output would be good for me so that we know which parts of app to focus on more. Like for sample above I am aiming for an output as simple as:

```
problems = {
'color_theme': 3,
'app_settings': 2,
'crashing' : 2}
```

So I kinda wants labeling and how much time a label is occured based on to which label a review belongs. For which I have been using manual going throw reviews and understanding whats its about add a count to the relevant bug or if it does not exist, file it which is not getting any easier with ever-increasing number of app reviews. Also the problem is I cannot train a model with predefined labels because:

1. I do not have labels for reviews. If we have to go through each review to know what problem is it talking about (i.e. to label it), we would just have filed it as well and would know what we have to work on.
2. I do not know in advance what problems are gonna come in future so even if we somehow label all at some point in time, it wouldn't be enough as some unseen problem may come and we have to do again.
3. Even if we have a system of labeling somehow, how would we update model, like do we define a new model with a different architecture for ever changing labels?

So under these circumstances, I was trying to figure out an AI approach to ease in my situation. I am pretty good at python and do have working knowledge of keras/tensorflow and other libraries but none of them seem to have such flexible model approach. I was going through Google Cloud Platform's AI platform as well but it could do sentiment analysis to an extent but not understand in an app context that e.g. button is a part of UI and color as well. So how could I approach this problem in a more elegant way?

P.S.  Its not really just sentiment analysis as I am getting this response a lot when I discuss this problem. I really only care about negative ratings so for filtering maybe but the actual target is to gather info about how much each problem bothers users and how many users are affected by it so it is not exactly like that. So back to the question:

**How to assign or add a new problem/bug label to an ever-increasing collection of reviews to do analyses with?**

Comment: The primary problem seems to be trying to extract a consistent label for user issues based on the human tendency to describe things in different ways.  You might try developing a set of key words .  Once you have a set of key words, you can count the occurrence of these keywords in the issue reports and based on the highest frequency occurrence of a keyword assign a label to the problem.  If the issue doesn't contain a minimal threshold of keywords, it could be flagged for special attention.  Issues requiring special attention can be used to add new keywords to your set.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems to solve:

1. Find samples which actually describe a problem. So not just 'good overall' but  more like 'Functional but Horrible UI'.
2. Find accurate categories (such as *UI*, *Crashes* etc.).
3. Classify data into those categories without labeled data.
4. Redo 2 and 3 for new data.

Problems in detail:

**1.** is probably straight forward, you could either use a sentiment analysis or classify them in *relevant*- *unrelevant*  by some sort of [active-learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_learning_(machine_learning))-algorithm. For example there is [this](https://github.com/modAL-python/modAL) python library for active-learning.

**2.** is more difficult. You need to activlely look into the data (only the data filtered by 1.), probably using some clustering algorithms and using your domain knowledge to identify useful categories.

**3.** is the same as 1. but with different labels and only on the data filtered by 1. By using active-learning you don't actually need labeled data, but you will label them when the model asks for it. This results in a multi-label-classification. With a multi-label-classification, it is possible that a sample is not labeled any of your categories. Let's call them 'no-category'-samples.

**4.** Now you have a pipeline which classifies data into categories. Once in a while, you would have to check the list of 'no-category'-samples and redo 2. Are there some useful new categories in those 'no-category'-samples? If yes, add the new category to your label-set and (re)train the multi-label-classification. If you have used a one-vs-rest approach, you can simple add the new model, no need to retrain the existing ones.
I guess it would be difficult to automate this step, as identifing useful categories needs domain knowledge. In a productive environment I would probably install an  email-notification if there are a certain number of new 'no-category'-samples. Every 100 new 'no-categories' you would have a look at the data and identify possible new categories.

Answer (score 1):

## Use clustering for automatic categorization

Here is an example of how you can use Tensorflow's sentence feature extraction and Sklearns autoclustering to cluster your info

First let's set up the imports and data

```
import tensorflow_hub as hub
model = hub.KerasLayer("https://tfhub.dev/google/nnlm-en-dim128/2")
```

You can read all about tensorflow hub online.  It provides pre-trained models for language and images.  Basically we are going to use it to extract 128 features out of your sentences.  I don't know what the features are, but they are 'semantic' in nature, so it is good enough to just compare the features of one sentence to the features of another for similarity.

Now for your data.  I added a few more examples that are similar to some.

```
data = ['Functional but Horrible UI', 'Really bad UI but works', 'hate the UI but functions',
    'Great everything works well', 'plus plus on it all working nicely', 'it all works like I expect',
    'I struggled finding plus button because of theme colors in dark mode', 'dark mode isnt good for my eyes'
    'Keeps stopping on Android 10', 'the Android 10 install crashes', 'what is with Android 10 not work'
    'I like the functionaity but color theme could be better', 'better colours please', 'what is with the horrible colors?'
    'Consistently crashing. Uninstalled', 'crashes all the time', 'why u crash so much ... crash crash crash',
    'Good overall', 'good', 'works', 'overall it is good',
    'sfdfsdlfksd',
    'I lost in complex settings',
    'Configuring app is really a headache',
    'aaaaaaaaaaaaa']
```

Next, we use the model to get the features from each sentence

```
data_as_latent = model(data).numpy()
data_as_latent.shape

# (22, 128)
```

And now we use sklearn to cluster the sentences.  I first use TruncatedSVD to reduce the dimensionality of the data first from 128 down to 12.  The reason for this is that BayesianGaussianMixture (the clustering code) doesn't do well with a lot of dimensions

```
from sklearn.decomposition import TruncatedSVD
from sklearn.mixture import BayesianGaussianMixture

def reduceDimensions(latents):
    svd = TruncatedSVD(n_components=12)
    svd.fit(latents)
    return svd.transform(latents).tolist()

def cluster(data_as_latent, clusters=4):
    bgm = BayesianGaussianMixture(n_components=clusters)
    bgm.fit(data_as_latent)
    return bgm.predict(data_as_latent)

data_as_smaller = reduceTo2D(data_as_latent)
data_as_cluster = cluster(data_as_smaller)
```

And now we get the output and see the magic!

```
for phrase,cluster in zip(data,data_as_cluster):
    print(f'Assigned cluster {cluster} to phrase : {phrase}')

Assigned cluster 0 to phrase : Functional but Horrible UI
Assigned cluster 0 to phrase : Really bad UI but works
Assigned cluster 0 to phrase : hate the UI but functions
Assigned cluster 0 to phrase : Great everything works well
Assigned cluster 3 to phrase : plus plus on it all working nicely
Assigned cluster 3 to phrase : it all works like I expect
Assigned cluster 3 to phrase : I struggled finding plus button because of theme colors in dark mode
Assigned cluster 2 to phrase : dark mode isnt good for my eyesKeeps stopping on Android 10
Assigned cluster 0 to phrase : the Android 10 install crashes
Assigned cluster 2 to phrase : what is with Android 10 not workI like the functionaity but color theme could be better
Assigned cluster 1 to phrase : better colours please
Assigned cluster 2 to phrase : what is with the horrible colors?Consistently crashing. Uninstalled
Assigned cluster 0 to phrase : crashes all the time
Assigned cluster 0 to phrase : why u crash so much ... crash crash crash
Assigned cluster 1 to phrase : Good overall
Assigned cluster 1 to phrase : good
Assigned cluster 0 to phrase : works
Assigned cluster 1 to phrase : overall it is good
Assigned cluster 0 to phrase : sfdfsdlfksd
Assigned cluster 0 to phrase : I lost in complex settings
Assigned cluster 2 to phrase : Configuring app is really a headache
Assigned cluster 0 to phrase : aaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

Looks like the clusters did a bit better than random.  With a lot more examples the clustering will work better.

## Handling outliers

You can handle outliers using a very similar technique but with a different Sklearn function.  Here is a video I made https://youtu.be/rGRS-fbpbB4 that shows the details of that.

## Finding phrases that are similar to other phrases

Say we want to find all the phrases that are really similar to `crashes all the time`.  We can use **cosine similarity** to find sentences that have very similar latent spaces like so:

```
import scipy
similarity = scipy.spatial.distance.cosine
reference = model(['crashes all the time']).numpy()[0]
scores = [similarity(reference,value) for value in data_as_latent]
for phrase,score in sorted( list(zip(data,scores)), key=lambda x: x[1]):
    print(f'Score {int(100 - score*100)} to phrase : {phrase}')
```

and your results look like this

```
Score 100 to phrase : crashes all the time
Score 49 to phrase : hate the UI but functions
Score 48 to phrase : why u crash so much ... crash crash crash
Score 37 to phrase : the Android 10 install crashes
Score 28 to phrase : I struggled finding plus button because of theme colors in dark mode
Score 28 to phrase : it all works like I expect
Score 26 to phrase : plus plus on it all working nicely
Score 26 to phrase : Great everything works well
Score 21 to phrase : Really bad UI but works
Score 21 to phrase : what is with Android 10 not workI like the functionaity but color theme could be better
Score 20 to phrase : Configuring app is really a headache
Score 18 to phrase : I lost in complex settings
Score 17 to phrase : what is with the horrible colors?Consistently crashing. Uninstalled
Score 15 to phrase : dark mode isnt good for my eyesKeeps stopping on Android 10
Score 14 to phrase : Good overall
Score 13 to phrase : overall it is good
Score 10 to phrase : good
Score 10 to phrase : works
Score 9 to phrase : sfdfsdlfksd
Score 4 to phrase : better colours please
Score 3 to phrase : Functional but Horrible UI
Score -26 to phrase : aaaaaaaaaaaaa
```